# Build failed Spring Boot Plugin was not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, gradle-plugin

I download a repo 'gs-handling-form-submission' from spring.io and now I'm trying to build: `gradle build`

Following Error has being triggered

```
 * Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\gs-handling-form-submission\complete\build.gradle' line: 11

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.4.2'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.4.2')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

I already added a repo url, changed spring.boot version, added `buildscript.repositories()` at the first line, even doing that, I can't get to compile.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url: "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Where did you download this project? I had a look [here](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-handling-form-submission/tree/main/initial), and it's using a more up to data version. Have you tried this one?

Comment: Yeap, on the project, it is using `2.6.3`, I already tried it, added `id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.3.RELEASE'`, removed `RELEASE`, changed the version, but didnt work

Comment: You may need to set up custom repositories for gradle plugins. Take a look [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:custom_plugin_repositories). The `repositories{}` block in `build.gradle` only applies for dependencies, but not for plugins.

Comment: @RatzzFatzz technically I must download the plugins, and point the folder manually?

Comment: No, it basically works the same as for dependencies, but has to be in the `settings.gradle`. The most common repos should suffice. The example I am using in one of [my projects](https://github.com/RatzzFatzz/Minecraft-Fly-Mod/blob/master/settings.gradle)

Comment: In repositories can you add `gradlePluginPortal()` and retry?

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the `build.gradle`, removing `:` url, was possible to build

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```